# Which ORM can do this?

Tags: orm

Apologies for the shopping list, but I've played with a few ORM-type libraries, and most are good, but none have done everything :) On my next project, am hoping to find one that can do a few more things out of the box. Have you got any good suggestions?

This is what I am looking for:

1. Easily select deeply nested data.

   for example, PHP Yii's CActiveRecord can do something like this: Contact::model()->with('phone_numbers', 'addresses', 'createdBy.user.company')->findAll();
2. Easily create/return deeply nested JSON from the database or ORM
3. Easily load deeply nested JSON data, validate it, and save it to the database correctly
4. Supports optimistic concurrency control
5. Handles multi-tenant systems gracefully

Comment: Why the votes to close? At least add a comment if you do so

Comment: Shopping questions are not universally popular in stackexchange circles and this question is very tersely worded. If you flesh out the question with some more context about the requirements then you might get better engagement from the community.  The question was originally migrated from dba.se because it is primarily related to application development, rather than database design.

Comment: Is this question specific to PHP (I had to look up Yii CActiveRecord to even make that guess)?  Looking at your user profile also implies PHP.

Comment: @MichaelMaddox, not php specific. I'm just curious if there is an ORM type library that can do some or all of these things. I know that ADO.Net can do optimistic concurrency, but not sure about the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Easily select deeply nested data / Easily create/return deeply nested
>   JSON from the database or ORM

Yet to find one...you need a generic way to convert to/from objects, arrays, json in and out, recursively

> Easily load deeply nested JSON data, validate it, and save it to the
>   database correctly

Yet to find one.

> Supports optimistic concurrency control

Doctrine or brew your own w a "version" counter on a record

> Handles multi-tenant systems gracefully

Ruby ActiveRecord  + Postgres

Answer (score 0):

ORM stands for Object-Relational mapper. It lets you convert from the world of rows to the world of objects and associations between these objects. Nothing in both worlds has anything to do with JSON or XML serialization. In order to achieve what you want you will need to employ separate serialization framework. It also looks like you don't need ORM because you don't plan on having an actual Object model, you seem to be thinking in terms of 'data' not 'objects', you just need a 'glue' between a database and network app.